# Cannot upload file with custom php function

Tags: php, file-upload

I try using function to upload different kind of file by giving it variables. As shown below:

```
<?
function fn_fileUpload($data,$dir,$uid){
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cgi-bin/connect.php");
    if(isset($data) && $data['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
        $fileTmpPath = $data['tmp_name'];
        $fileName = $data['name'];
        $fileSize = $data['size'];
        $fileType = $data['type'];
        $fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
        $fileExt = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));
        $newFileName = $uid . '.' . $fileExt;
        //check file ext
        $okEXT = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png','doc','docx','pdf');
        if (in_array($fileExt, $okEXT)) {
            $fileDir = '/'.$dir.'/';
            $dest_path = $fileDir.$newFileName;          
            if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path)){
                try{
                    $stmt2=$mysqli->prepare("insert into job_file (jfile_id, job_id, jfile_name, jfile_size, jfile_type, jfile_ext) valies(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    $stmt2->bind_param('iisiss',$zero,$uid,$newFileName,$fileSize,$fileType,$fileExt);
                    $stmt2->execute();
                    $result = 'ok';
                }catch(mysqli_sql_exception $err){
                    $result=$err;
                }
            }else{
              $result = 'Cannot upload file!';
            }
        }//in_array
    }//if(isset
    return $result;
}
?>
```

And this is how to use:

```
//upload file
$job_file=fn_fileUpload($_FILES['job_file'],'uploads',$_POST['passport_id']);
//upload photo
$job_img=fn_fileUpload($_FILES['job_img'],'photos',$_POST['passport_id']);
```

From here, the function always return : `Cannot upload file!`. At first I think. It might have something to do with `move_uploaded_file` but the file was there in `/uploads` directory but not with `/photos`. Both directories `CHMOD 755` (tried 777 but no luck).

The db went through correctly. Is there any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `/uploads` means a directory named `uploads` in the *filesystem root*. Is that actually where the directory is, or are you looking for `./uploads`? (Or equivalent relative to something specific, like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads'`.)

Comment: I created a new dir name `uploads` waiting for the file to fill in. So what's the point?

Comment: `./` means the current directory. `/` means the root directory. Very different. Try it.

Comment: I still don't get it. Why you're mentioned `./` despite there's nothing to do with my code.

Comment: You have `$fileDir = '/'.$dir.'/';`. I’m asking if you mean `$fileDir = './'.$dir.'/';`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I change the way uploading now.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `move_uploaded_file()` ONCE on a temporary file that has been uploaded through a form. This function destroys the temporary file after it has been moved, so the for the first upload in the uploads directory you can do it well but in for the second one no.

Comment: But I call the function separately. Does this matter?

Comment: @Wilf Absolutely! because the first function call changes the temp source and moves it, so you don't access to it to upload it again in another directory.

Comment: I got it, now I changed the whole way of uploading separately. Thanks.